# Is there a way to see the code that creates a view in SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql-server

I want to see the underlying code for how a view is created in SQL server management studio. Is there a way to do this?

I want to see any date filters, etc, applied to this view in hard code.

Answer (score 8):

Right click the view, select `Script View as`, `CREATE To`, `New query editor window`.

Comment: Sorry to jump on such an old thread, but I thought this was just what I was looking for except when I do this I get the message - Property TextHeader is not available for View [XYZ]. This property may not exist for thi object r may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights. The text is encrypted. the user I'm connecting with only has READ access, so I presume this is the issue?

Comment: at least in SSMS 18.12.1, there is no `CREATE to` option.  `UPDATE to` is an option, but it does not report what query underlies the view.

Answer (score 5):

```
select text from sys.syscomments where id = object_id ('dbo.myview')
```

---

```
select definition from sys.all_sql_modules where object_id = object_id ('dbo.myview')
```

---

```
select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = object_id ('dbo.myview')
```

---

```
select object_definition (object_id ('dbo.myview')) object_definition
```

---

```
sp_helptext 'dbo.myview'
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the View, select Design.  You will see the designer/table layout, Column chooser, the Select statement and a window for results at the bottom.